# Web-Forms - How a User-Control access another User-Control

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have two User-Controls and both are referenced in an .aspx page. How one User-Control can access the other User-Control, not from the code-behind?

For example?

[image]

Comment: Maybe register one control inside the other before adding to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you have 2 User Controls, you can access them by ID by going to the parent and using FindControl. In this example they are both the same UC, but that does not matter.

```
<uc1:WebUserControl1 runat="server" ID="WebUserControl1" />
<uc1:WebUserControl1 runat="server" ID="WebUserControl2" />
```

Then in code behind of `WebUserControl1`

```
//find the user control on the parent page
var usercontrol = Parent.FindControl("WebUserControl1") as UserControl;

//find the textbox in that usercontrol
var textbox = usercontrol.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;

//do something with the textbox
textbox.Text = "Text in UserControl 1";
```